# Why? BUG: Bad page map in process *process* pte:b3e05275201 pmd:238adf067

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux

I develop a kernel module using DMA `dma_alloc_coherent()` and `remap_pfn_range()`.
Sometimes, when I close the app that opened the character device, I get the following message in `dmesg`. That leads to a kernel panic few seconds (random) later.

```
[ 3275.772330] BUG: Bad page map in process gnome-shell  pte:b3e05275201 pmd:238adf067
[ 3275.772337] addr:00007f20bce00000 vm_flags:08000070 anon_vma:          (null) mapping:ffff969f236dcdd0 index:b8
[ 3275.772375] vma->vm_ops->fault: xfs_filemap_fault+0x0/0x30 [xfs]
[ 3275.772400] vma->vm_file->f_op->mmap: xfs_file_mmap+0x0/0x80 [xfs]
[ 3275.772413] CPU: 5 PID: 4809 Comm: gnome-shell Kdump: loaded Tainted: G           OE  ------------   3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64 #1
[ 3275.772416] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/PRIME H370M-PLUS, BIOS 1801 10/17/2019
[ 3275.772417] Call Trace:
[ 3275.772425]  [<ffffffffbb97ffa5>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
[ 3275.772432]  [<ffffffffbb3ee311>] print_bad_pte+0x1f1/0x290
[ 3275.772436]  [<ffffffffbb3f0676>] vm_normal_page+0xa6/0xb0
[ 3275.772440]  [<ffffffffbb3f0ccb>] unmap_page_range+0x64b/0xc80
[ 3275.772444]  [<ffffffffbb3f1381>] unmap_single_vma+0x81/0xf0
[ 3275.772448]  [<ffffffffbb3f2db9>] unmap_vmas+0x49/0x90
[ 3275.772454]  [<ffffffffbb3fcdbc>] exit_mmap+0xac/0x1a0
[ 3275.772458]  [<ffffffffbb454db5>] ? flush_old_exec+0x3b5/0x950
[ 3275.772463]  [<ffffffffbb298667>] mmput+0x67/0xf0
[ 3275.772467]  [<ffffffffbb454f00>] flush_old_exec+0x500/0x950
[ 3275.772472]  [<ffffffffbb4b38d0>] load_elf_binary+0x340/0xdb0
[ 3275.772476]  [<ffffffffbb52cd53>] ? ima_get_action+0x23/0x30
[ 3275.772479]  [<ffffffffbb52c26e>] ? process_measurement+0x8e/0x250
[ 3275.772482]  [<ffffffffbb52c729>] ? ima_bprm_check+0x49/0x50
[ 3275.772486]  [<ffffffffbb45454a>] search_binary_handler+0x9a/0x1c0
[ 3275.772490]  [<ffffffffbb455c56>] do_execve_common.isra.24+0x616/0x880
[ 3275.772493]  [<ffffffffbb456159>] SyS_execve+0x29/0x30
[ 3275.772498]  [<ffffffffbb993478>] stub_execve+0x48/0x80
```

- Here the process is `gnome-shell` but that doesn't mean anything, I saw lots of different processes, it can be anything.
- In `BUG: Bad page map in process gnome-shell  pte:b3e05275201 pmd:238adf067`

  - *238adf**067*** is the base physical address of a coherent memory allocated by my driver, with an offset of **0x67** (0x238adf**000**)
  - All those messages **always** come with the physical address and **0x67** offset!
- Those prints are generated from here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7cf726a59435301046250c42131554d9ccc566b8/mm/memory.c#L536

I tried to remove everything useless, here is the code showing the order I call API functions:

```c
const struct file_operations pcie_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = chr_open,
    .release = chr_release,
    .mmap = chr_mmap,
};

static int chr_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
  struct custom_data *custom_data;
  struct chr_dev_bookkeep *chr_dev_bk;

  chr_dev_bk = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct chr_dev_bookkeep, cdev);
  custom_data = kzalloc(sizeof(*custom_data), GFP_KERNEL);

  filp->private_data = custom_data;
  return 0;
}

static int chr_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
  struct custom_data *custom_data;
  custom_data = filp->private_data;
  // ==========================> FREED HERE <================================
  dma_free_coherent(&pdev->dev, size, virt_addr, bus_addr);
  filp->private_data = NULL;
  kfree(custom_data);
  return 0;
}

static int chr_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma) {
  int ret;
  struct custom_data *custom_data;
  custom_data = filp->private_data;
  chr_dev_bk = custom_data->chr_dev_bk;

  vm_len = PAGE_ALIGN(vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start);
  vma->vm_flags |= VM_PFNMAP | VM_DONTCOPY | VM_DONTEXPAND;
  vma->vm_private_data = custom_data;/*not really used because no vm_operations_struct.close*/

  virt_addr = dma_alloc_coherent(&pdev->dev, vm_len, &bus_addr, GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_ZERO);

  set_memory_uc((unsigned long)virt_addr, (vm_len / PAGE_SIZE));
  vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);
  ret = remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start,
                        bus_addr >> PAGE_SHIFT,
                        vm_len,
                        vma->vm_page_prot);
  return ret;
}
```

I believe that bug can't come from my application code.

- `mmap(nullptr, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, filehandler, 0);`.

Edit:

The @Ian Abbott's comment made me look at the kernel source code and I found a comment at `dma_mmap_attrs()` (=`dma_mmap_coherent()`): https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/include/linux/dma-mapping.h#L309

> The coherent DMA buffer must not be freed by the
> driver until the user space mapping has been released.

- **Has been released**, I guess that means not **during** the release.
- I believe that's also true for memory mapped with `remap_pfn_range()`.

I'll write an answer if that was the problem.

Comment: Firstly, it is highly unusual to allocate the buffer within the `mmap` handler. When is the buffer freed? What happens if there is a second `mmap` call? Secondly, you should be using `dma_mmap_coherent` instead of `remap_pfn_range`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks. Unusual isn't wrong but I can move it for sure if that's the problem. The buffer(s) is freed at the file's release (cf.code sample), even if not freed, the kernel shouldn't use it anymore = different problem. I removed the code that handles the Nth mmap() call, it isn't a problem for several reasons also there is no 2nd call in my app. I saw some examples using `remap_pfn_range()` directly, I'll move to `dma_mmap_coherent()`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A minimal explanation would be welcome. What are `pdev`, `size`, `bus_addr`, `virt_addr`, `vm_len`? Most importantly though, why are you not checking for errors after each function call?

Comment: It's quite obvious I map coherent memory to user-space. I discarded all those information in the code sample to stay short. All those var have the right type (-Wall), I edited my question with a potential hint. It works perfectly until the release, not always.

Comment: @IanAbbott `dma_mmap_coherent()` returns `-ENXIO` which is the default return value. `CONFIG_MMU` is set and `CONFIG_ARCH_NO_COHERENT_DMA_MMAP` isn't. It seems nobody uses the `dma_mmap_coherent()` call then won't use it.

Comment: Seems like you could use the uio framework for you driver.  It would get the details of mapping and unmapping correct.